# Angular build failing due to Uglify.js

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Today morning we just ran into an issue where we had the build failing and the reason was totally unknown. The stack trace is not revealing anything apart form the Uglify files and its all of a sudden we have encountered this. I am using Angular CLI

```
ng build --target=production --env=prod

 18% building modules 67/67 modules 0 activeTemplate parse warnings:                  
The <template> element is deprecated. Use <ng-template> instead ("[WARNING ->]<template #innerView></template>
<template #template let-ctx>
    <template [swapCmp]="ctx.component""): ng:///Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/angular2-modal/esm/overlay/overlay.component.d.ts.ModalOverlay.html@0:0
Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for UserDetail in /Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/src/app/models/user-detail.model.ts: (?). This will become an error in Angular v5.x
Hash: 57f5ee6a7de2d0427083                                                                 
Time: 83888ms
chunk    {0} main.72d8abfc264b3e8c979e.bundle.js (main) 3.04 MB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} scripts.155fe32b210641a6bc1c.bundle.js (scripts) 1.15 MB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.68eaa60430e83a5adf34.bundle.css (styles) 599 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.7b3b095ed3817b60967b.bundle.js (vendor) 4.05 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.27f2c1c1353b86214c6d.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in main.72d8abfc264b3e8c979e.bundle.js from UglifyJs
TypeError: Cannot set property 'fixed' of undefined
    at TreeWalker.eval [as visit] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:5581:25)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1339:24)
    at AST_This._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:480:24)
    at AST_Dot.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1061:29)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1343:21)
    at AST_Dot._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1060:24)
    at AST_Dot.walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:483:21)
    at TreeWalker.eval [as visit] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:5719:31)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1339:24)
    at AST_ForIn._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:653:24)
    at walk_body (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:530:17)
    at AST_BlockStatement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:541:13)
    at TreeWalker._visit (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:1343:21)
    at AST_BlockStatement._walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:540:24)
    at AST_BlockStatement.walk (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:483:21)
    at TreeWalker.eval [as visit] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:1:1), <anonymous>:5698:42)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vetahealth-admin@0.0.0 build: `ng build --target=production --env=prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vetahealth-admin@0.0.0 build script 'ng build --target=production --env=prod'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vetahealth-admin package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ng build --target=production --env=prod
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs vetahealth-admin
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls vetahealth-admin
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/shivganesh/.npm/_logs/2017-06-02T22_40_30_878Z-debug.log
```

I am totally confused why is Uglify behaving this way. Till last monday it was all fine and today all of a sudden it broke. I have also pasted below my package.json and the npm logs.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vetahealth-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "build": "ng build --target=production --env=prod",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "typedoc": "typedoc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.3.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "9.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.2.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^4.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "npm": "^5.0.1",
    "pikaday": "^1.5.1",
    "primeng": "^4.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "slimscroll": "^0.9.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "compass-mixins": "0.12.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.51",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.65",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.27",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "^5.4.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.3"
  }
}
```

**Npm Logs**

```
Shivs-MacBook-Pro:Physician shivganesh$ cat /Users/shivganesh/.npm/_logs/2017-06-02T22_40_30_878Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.9.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~prebuild: vetahealth-admin@0.0.0
6 silly lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~prebuild: no script for prebuild, continuing
7 info lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: vetahealth-admin@0.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
10 verbose lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician
11 silly lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'ng build --target=production --env=prod' ]
12 silly lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle vetahealth-admin@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
14 verbose stack Error: vetahealth-admin@0.0.0 build: `ng build --target=production --env=prod`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid vetahealth-admin@0.0.0
16 verbose cwd /Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician
17 error Darwin 16.6.0
18 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
19 error node v7.9.0
20 error npm  v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error vetahealth-admin@0.0.0 build: `ng build --target=production --env=prod`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the vetahealth-admin@0.0.0 build script 'ng build --target=production --env=prod'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the vetahealth-admin package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     ng build --target=production --env=prod
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs vetahealth-admin
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls vetahealth-admin
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: @Arvind any Idea what went wrong?

Comment: I guess some of your dependency stopped being compiled to ES5 that is needed for UglifyJS. It's very hard to debug it, however if you use npm v5 you can see in `package-lock.json` file git history what has been recently updated.

Comment: @DanielKucal Where should I find Package Lock file. I am using the latest version on npm

Comment: in the exactly same directory where is your `package.json`

Comment: @DanielKucal Crap... :( I dont have it. Neither we ever generated it :( I am screwed. Shall I check the external dependencies recently added. I can remove them one by one and then check out whether it works.

Comment: Then for a fast work-around I'd remove all `^` and `~` characters from not-at-all-trust-worthy dependencies and `npm install` again

Comment: @DanielKucal now I am getting this

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newLine' of undefined
    at Object.getNewLineCharacter (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9514:20)
    at Object.createCompilerHost (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63770:26)
    at Object.ngcLoader (/Users/shivganesh/Documents/Vetahealth/CODE/Physician/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:380:33)
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Comment: So that's something different, take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3781 and good luck

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Maybe try to update to latest angular cli version (now it's 1.1) as you are using the latest angular version.. also, update @angular/animations to latest version.

Comment: Also fix the error in your code "TypeError: Cannot set property 'fixed' of undefined" and update the old template tag to <ng-template>

Comment: @IsakLaFleur Is there a way to debug or see all the logs so that I can follow things out. Getting difficult to figure things out.

Comment: Fix the two knows errors/warnings you have, after you have solved them. Send me the new error logs (you need to fix, property "fixed"..

Comment: Btw.. why do you have "install" and "npm" as dependencies?

Comment: @IsakLaFleur OMG I never saw that. Thats a grave blunder. I removed but still build fails.... feels like killing myself. Been Two Days now.

Comment: Try to update your post with latest error message and package.json file after you have fixed the things I asked you to do in previous comments and I can have a new look at it. Or post a GitHub link to the repo and I can have a look

Comment: @IsakLaFleur It worked through a little tweak. I will explain that in the anwwer but I would like to know how to create a package-lock.json. I dont have it in my repo.

Comment: @IsakLaFleur so I created a new project and matched the dependencies, then it required some adjusting with the versions and things started working!! :D Thanks anyways

Comment: Glad to here you fixed it. I'm pretty sure it was the package json lock file. I remember I had I similar error. I removed the lock file and then updated the package json, removed/updated the the latest angular version and cli version and installled and it worked! :)

Comment: @IsakLaFleur the fun part is my project does not have a lock file as such and that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

So the way you can solve such issues is as follows:-

1. Check whether the previous releases are also having the same issue, which in my case turned out to be true. This way I eliminated the doubt that the developers or the solution went wrong somewhere.
2. Now go ahead and create a new project with the latest version of angular-cli
3. The above step gives you an option of getting a blank project with the working dependencies in place.
4. List the various dependencies and then try to merge them into the correct place.
5. You may find there are mismatch or inconsistency but give a try to get at least the versions mentioned for the angular files.

Thats it. You are done. I did have to uninstall the ng version since the version of angular-cli on my system was higher than what the project uses.

Hope this was helpful.